# Component in wrapPageElement rerenders – GatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I've installed `gatsby-plugin-layout` to keep the Layout component persistent. In the Layout component I have a component called RandomBackground which does exactly that, it shows a random background image on page load.

However the background image changes on subsequent page changes, which is not wanted behaviour.

What am I doing wrong? Condensed code below.

**gatsby-config.js**

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-layout`,
  options: {
    component: require.resolve(`./src/components/Layout`),
  },
}
```

**Layout**

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Content>
        <main>{children}</main>
      </Content>

      <RandomBackground />
    </>
  )
}
```

**RandomBackground**

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'gatsby-image'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

const BackgroundImg = styled(Image)`
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
`

const randomGenerator = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
}

const RandomBackground = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query ImageQuery {
      wordPress {
        pageBy(uri: "home") {
          homeFields {
            backgroundImage {
              images {
                sourceUrl
                imageFile {
                  childImageSharp {
                    fluid {
                      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const images = data.wordPress.pageBy.homeFields.backgroundImage.images
  const randomPosition = randomGenerator(0, images.length - 1)
  const randomizedImage = images[randomPosition].imageFile.childImageSharp
  console.log('render') // pops up in console every page change

  return (
    <BackgroundImg fluid={randomizedImage.fluid} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried storing the `randomizedImage` in state on the Layout component? I have a feeling your re-render triggers the change.

Comment: @Sarreph Do you mean doing the logic of the image fetching in `Layout` and passing the result down to `RandomBackground`?

Comment: See my answer — you shouldn't need to move your logic to `Layout` as your state should still persist in `RandomBackground`... If that doesn't work then consider moving it to Layout, although I have tested this on a nested component within a Layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background image is changing on a 'page change' because each time the page changes, your `Layout` component re-renders.

In order to persist your background image, store your random number generation in state on the `RandomBackground` like so:

#### RandomBackground

```
import {useState} from 'react';
...
const RandomBackground = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query ImageQuery {
      wordPress {
        pageBy(uri: "home") {
          homeFields {
            backgroundImage {
              images {
                sourceUrl
                imageFile {
                  childImageSharp {
                    fluid {
                      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const images = data.wordPress.pageBy.homeFields.backgroundImage.images
  const randomPositionInitial = randomGenerator(0, images.length - 1);
  const [randomPosition] = useState(randomPositionInitial);
  const randomizedImage = images[randomPosition].imageFile.childImageSharp
  console.log('render') // pops up in console every page change

  return (
    <BackgroundImg fluid={randomizedImage.fluid} />
  )
}
```